# influence of the wheels on the vehicle movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm new in Unity. I want to do that wheels (cylinders) in this car will turn around if I press "up" button on my keyboard.
This is the code I've written:

```
var forwardSpeed: float = 3;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {
    var forwardMoveAmount = Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*forwardSpeed;
    transform.Rotate(0, forwardMoveAmount, 0);
}
```

OK. Wheels are turning around, but my car is still at the same place. What should I do to move this car?
[image]

PS: can you explain me, why this cylinder rotates correctly, when I use Y axis? It should be z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying the distance scalar to a rotate function, and not translating (Moving) the object.

`transform.Rotate` will rotate the object.

`transform.Translate` will move the object.

Pick an object on your desk. If you rotate it 90 degrees twice, it will be rotated 180 degrees but still be in the same place. Now imagine every time you rotate that object, you move it in the direction it's facing by a couple inches. After 4 cycles, the object will have completed a full circuit of 360 degrees.

To represent this in code:

```
var forwardSpeed: float = 3; // Tweak me
var turnAngle:    float = 1; // Tweak me

function Start () {

}

function Update () {
    // Rotate first
    transform.Rotate(0, Vector3.right * turnAngle, 0);
    // Move forward along the rotated axis
    transform.Translate(0, Vector3.forward * forwardSpeed, 0);
}
```

Comment: but I thought that if I rotate wheels, physics engine will allow me to move this car.

Comment: Pick an object on your desk. If you rotate it 90 degrees twice, it will be rotated 180 degrees but still be in the same place. Now imagine every time you rotate that object, you move it in the direction it's facing by a couple inches. After 4 cycles, the object will have completed a full circuit of 360 degrees.

Comment: so what should I do to make my car more realistic? transform will move my car on plane, but what about terrain? what if I want to ride to the top of mountain?

Comment: Have you added any physics to the car? Specifically RigidBody or CharacterController? If you want it to move along terrain and other objects with physics, you'll need to put one of those on the car object. You can find them under Components->Physics

Answer (score 2):

For physics based wheels, you probably want wheel colliders. Their use is pretty well documented here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-WheelCollider.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to also explicitly move the car at the same time, using presumably `transform.position`, `transform.Translate()`, or something similar on the parent car object.

Comment: but I thought that if I rotate wheels, physics engine will allow me to move this car.